# Keep track of user activity on each page

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on bank web application in angular 7. I want to track user activity on each page like how much time user spending on each page, click activity etc.. I have not found any solution.

Comment: Set the counter and trace mouse move

Answer (score 2):

There is an [matamo](https://matomo.org/), for that where we can track user actions, but it is **paid**. In **Angular**, we can implement the same using [ngx-matamo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-matomo)

If you want a custom solution, we can implement logic in the **main App component**,
to **watch the router changes** and implement the **time we spent on each page.**

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-bys6bq?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Use [matomo](https://matomo.org/?fireglass_rsn=true) and it is open source, an application which is written using PHP. You can simply download it and set it up in your premise. Then download plugin called **TagManager**(similar to Google tag manager). Add code in html snippet like this then you are done.

```
<!-- Matomo Tag Manager -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _mtm = window._mtm = window._mtm || [];
    _mtm.push({'mtm.startTime': (new Date().getTime()), 'event': 'mtm.Start'});
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.src='https://{$MATOMO_URL}/js/container_{$CONTAINER}.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
</script>
<!-- End Matomo Tag Manager -->
```